# An internal error was found for this API project : Google Places API

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am working with Google Places Web Service API, I have created the server key and also enabled the billing for a higher access/usage quota. However upon accessing the API in my C# Project, it gives me the following error...

```
"error_message" : "An internal error was found for this API project.",
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
```

However If I use the API URL generated by the application in the browser, I get the output as expected in the browser.

Recently I started working with Google Place API. I have created one server key for my current project. As I have to use Place API so I turned it on in Service page.

I have regenerated the SERVER KEY and also have verified it; I am sending 1 request per minute.

My Search URL looks like this...

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Hotel+Bellizio+New+York&sensor=false&type=lodging|establishment&key={MY_API_KEY}
```

It is not about the sensor=true/false parameter, as it failed to return with both values.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a lot of investigation across various aspects of the project, I have finally, with some tips available online, figured out the problem.

The problem was with .Net WebClient.DownloadString which I was using as it makes a call over POST, now I am using HttpClient which does a GET which is required by this API.

However I'm still at loss to understand why it worked on some machines and only blocked on a particular machine.